# how to make spring mvc functions available for rest calls

Tags: spring, rest, url, model-view-controller, call

I have a spring mvc application which runs correctly,now another colleague wants to call the same functions from another application but he needs REST URL of my functions.
how is it possible to provide the same functionality through spring REST?
is it just with new annotations .please provide some resource to show me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

when server has a service, only legal clients which had any contracts with server can access it. And clients can use service by the way such as: use RestTemplate to get/post request to URL of service, and clients can get data as JSON, or XML type if you have an equivalent object as this image:

[image]
Also, a service can be support as a interface, ex: google search is a service supported by google, but it's not rest service.

Answer (score 0):

If you know each other URL address you can consume each other REST API from java code by using RestTemplate object.

I would advise you to go over the Spring starter guide which deals with that issue, here is the link (Consuming a RESTful Web Service):

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/